# Jdeveloper - Unrecognized option: -jrockit

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, jrockit

Every time I try to run a weblogic webcenter application on Jdev I get the following error and I cant find any reference on how to fix this anywhere on the web.

> starting weblogic with Java version: Could not create the Java virtual
>   machine. Unrecognized option: -jrockit

Comment: whats the startup java command shown in the log? the one which shows weblogic trying to start?

Comment: I dont have access to it any more, but I do recall is was a long java -jrokit command.
I did however find a small temporary solution and that was replacing the JDK with Jrocket on my system, dont know what I did there but it was worth a try and it now seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try modifying the startWebLogic.cmd file (WIN7)

```
c:\users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system{version}\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
```

to contain

```
set JAVA_VM=-server
set MEM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Answer (score 4):

Jdeveloper 11g do not support jdk 1.7

> https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2482850

I fixed it by add to top of c:\users{user}\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system{version}\DefaultDomain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd:

```
set SUN_JAVA_HOME=E:\Oracle\Java\jdk1.6.0_37
set JAVA_VENDOR=Sun
```

Answer (score 1):

In OSX, look for the this folder `/Users/{USERNAME}/.jdeveloper/system{VERSION}/DefaultDomain/bin`

Edit the file `setDomainEnv.sh` and look for `SUN_JAVA_HOME` and make sure the value is the same value as your `JAVA_HOME`, i.e. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk${JDK_VERSION}.jdk/Contents/Home`, by default it seems it is set to an empty string `""`.

Edit the file `startWebLogic.sh` and add the following before `setDomainEnv.sh` is called.

`JAVA_VENDOR=Sun`

You can test it out by running `sh ./startWebLogic.sh`, if it runs with `-jrockit` error, then all is good :)

I've also tested with Java JDK 1.7 and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that older Weblogic Versions use the Java VM "JRockit"
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index.html

The JRockit VM is no longer supported in Java 7 or higher.

All of the other solutions here seem to be hacks and none of them helped me.
I had the same Problem with a Weblogic 10.3.5 and I found out, the installation was incorrect.

The Problem is, that there is no java version check in the installer, so if you don't know that you can't use Java 7 or higher you are screwed.

These steps fixed it for me:

- You need to make sure you have Java 6 or lower installed.
- Reinstall the Weblogic and make sure to specify the correct JDK